# Is there a way to sort an array by the second column from highest value to lowest value?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, multiple-columns

I am trying to sort my array "factor_groups" by the second column, which contains the f_pow values, from the highest to lowest. Ultimately, I am trying to produce a scatter plot of the three values, with f_cond on the x-axis, f_mom on the y, and using color to identify what the f_pow value is (0.7, 0.8, or 0.9) and the size of the marker to indicate how often it appeared in the factor_group array. The f_pow_count will be used for marker size and it needs to be sorted from highest to lowest so the largest sizes markers are plotted first and don't cover the smaller ones.

I have tried the argsort function but cant get it to work.

```
f_cond_plot=[]
f_pow_plot=[]
f_mom_plot=[]
factor_group={}
distinct_sets=[]


data_file = open('Ti=Te.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(data_file)


for row in csv_f:

    if i == 16:
        #print("end")
        break
    else:
        #print(i)
        Te_t[i] = float(row[3])
        Ti_t[i] = float(row[4])
        n_t[i] = float(row[5])
        L[i] = float(row[10])
        Te_u_div[i] = float(row[6])
        Ti_u_div[i] =  float(row[7])
        n_u_div[i] = float(row[8])
        q_par_div[i] = float(row[9])
        Tu_div[i] = float(Te_u_div[i]+Ti_u_div[i])
        c_s_div[i] = float(row[11])
        radius[i] = (row[0])
        IR_div[i] = float(row[2])

        i = i+1

f_cond=np.linspace(.1,.9,9)     
f_pow=np.linspace(.1,.9,9)
f_mom=np.linspace(.1,.9,9)

for a in f_cond:
    s=s+1
    for b in f_pow:
        for c in f_mom:
            factor[z]=[a,b,c]

            if y == 2:
                for x in range(0, len(Te_t)):

                     gamma = 7
                     c_s[x] = np.power([k_b*(Ti_t[x]+Te_t[x])*K_ev/(m_e+m_i)] , 0.5)
                     #print(c_s[x])
                     q_par[x] = gamma*n_t[x]*k_b*K_ev*(Ti_t[x]+Te_t[x])*c_s[x]*(1-b)
                     Tu[x] = np.power(np.power(Ti_t[x]+Te_t[x], (7/2))+(7/2)*a*q_par[x]*L[x]/ko_e , (2/7))
                     n_u_simp[x] = 2*n_t[x]*(Ti_t[x]+Te_t[x])/(c*Tu[x])
                     n_u_com[x] = np.power(m_i/(2*e*(Ti_t[x]+Te_t[x]))*4*np.power(q_par[x], 2)*np.power((7/2)*q_par[x]*L[x]/ko_e, (-4/7))/(np.power(gamma, 2)*e**2), 0.5)/c


                     if cs_lower_bound < c_s[x]/c_s_div[x] < cs_upper_bound and Tu_lower_bound < Tu[x]/Tu_div[x] < Tu_upper_bound and q_par_lower_bound < q_par[x]/q_par_div[x] < q_par_upper_bound:     
                        #This If statement has no bounds on q_par
                        #and 0.1 < q_par[x]/q_par_div[x] < 10

                        if nu_lower_bound < n_u_com[x]/n_u_div[x] < nu_upper_bound:
                            #nor u_lower_bound < n_u_simp[x]/n_u_div[x] < nu_upper_bound 

                            f_cond_plot.append(a)
                            f_pow_plot.append(b)
                            f_mom_plot.append(c)

                            f_cond_avg.append(a)
                            f_pow_avg.append(b)
                            f_mom_avg.append(c)

                            if x==0:
                                IR10_cnt=IR10_cnt+1
                            elif x==1:
                                IR11_cnt=IR11_cnt+1
                            elif x==2:
                                IR12_cnt=IR12_cnt+1
                            elif x==3:
                                IR13_cnt=IR13_cnt+1
                            elif x==4:
                                IR14_cnt=IR14_cnt+1
                            elif x==5:
                                IR15_cnt=IR15_cnt+1
                            elif x==6:
                                IR16_cnt=IR16_cnt+1
                            elif x==7:
                                IR17_cnt=IR17_cnt+1
                            elif x==8:
                                IR18_cnt=IR18_cnt+1
                            elif x==9:
                                IR19_cnt=IR19_cnt+1
                            elif x==10:
                                IR20_cnt=IR20_cnt+1
                            elif x==11:
                                IR21_cnt=IR21_cnt+1
                            elif x==12:
                                IR22_cnt=IR22_cnt+1
                            elif x==13:
                                IR23_cnt=IR23_cnt+1
                            elif x==14:
                                IR24_cnt=IR24_cnt+1
                            elif x==15:
                                IR25_cnt=IR25_cnt+1

                            number=number+1

            #cs_ratio=c_s/c_s_div
            Tu_ratio=Tu/Tu_div
            q_par_ratio=q_par/q_par_div
            nu_simp_ratio=n_u_simp/n_u_div
            nu_com_ratio=n_u_com/n_u_div

            #ratio[z]=["factors", factor[z], "Tu ratio" ,Tu_ratio, "heat flux ratio", q_par_ratio,"simple denisty ratio", nu_simp_ratio,"complex denisty ratio", nu_com_ratio]
            z=z+1  


f_cond_avg=np.array(f_cond_avg)
f_pow_avg=np.array(f_pow_avg)
f_mom_avg=np.array(f_mom_avg)


for t in range(0,number):
    factor_group [t]=[f_cond_plot[t], f_pow_plot[t], f_mom_plot[t]]       

print("first",factor_group)
count_pow_7=0
count_pow_8=0
count_pow_9=0
f_pow_color=np.zeros(len(f_pow_plot), dtype=str)

#Finds the value of f_pow that occurs most
for c in range(0,len(f_pow_plot)):
    if f_pow_plot[c]==0.7000000000000001:
        count_pow_7=count_pow_7+1
        f_pow_color[c]="blue"
        #print("0.7)",count_pow_7)

    elif f_pow_plot[c]==0.8:
        count_pow_8=count_pow_8+1
        f_pow_color[c]="red"
        #print("0.8)",count_pow_8)

    elif f_pow_plot[c]==0.9:
        count_pow_9=count_pow_9+1
        f_pow_color[c]="yellow"
        #print("0.9)",count_pow_9)

print("0.7)",count_pow_7)
print("0.8)",count_pow_8)            
print("0.9)",count_pow_9)

factor_group = np.argsort(factor_group,1)

print("sorted",factor_group)

plt.scatter(f_cond_plot, f_mom_plot, c=f_pow_color, s=factor_group[1])
plt.title("Scatter plot of factor sets that meet conditions")
plt.xlabel("Conduction Factor")
plt.ylabel("Momentum Factor")
plt.legend(f_pow_plot)
plt.show
```

I am getting the error: AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1

Comment: Try minimizing your sample code so that it demonstrates the problem but doesn't contain a lot of extraneous detail that distracts from the question.

Comment: You're using the axis argument instead of order: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html